# Cannot create Google_Client object

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I´m trying to make a simple php to get my Google Analytics data. 
But I´m still getting error 500 when running the script. I decided to comment all the code setting IDs, Developer keys etc. and the error appears when I´m creating Google_Client object.

In Google_Client.php I have **set_include_path('C:/.../Google_API/src');**

My index.php is located at **C:/.../Google_API/index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
print 'test'; // not printed
/* rest of code */
?>
```

I really do not know what I´m doing wrong. Is there something else what needs to be configured before I can create Google_Client?

The library I´m currently using is [here](https://google-api-php-client.googlecode.com/files/google-api-php-client-0.6.6.tar.gz).

Comment: Check what your error logs says, 9 out of 10 times it contains a good hint.

Comment: [22-Jul-2014 23:01:12] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Google CurlIO client requires the CURL PHP extension' in C:\web\WWW\Google_API\src\io\Google_CurlIO.php:47
Stack trace:
#0 C:\web\WWW\Google_API\src\Google_Client.php(107): Google_CurlIO->__construct()
#1 C:\web\WWW\Google_API\index.php(9): Google_Client->__construct()
#2 {main}
  thrown in C:\web\WWW\Google_API\src\io\Google_CurlIO.php on line 47

Comment: You might want to start by getting the most recent google php client lib https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl is not activated. Go to your php.ini file and remove the `;` from the line `extension=php_curl.dll`

Don't forget to restart the webserver.

Comment: Thanks... It worked. I spent so much time looking into Google_Client.php and I missed such easy solution as enabling extension.